# How is Cherry Darling firing the gun with her leg?

Tags: plot-explanation, planet-terror

In Planet Terror, Cherry Darling lost her leg and she was attached with a gun.

I am asking about the trigger.

[image]

How is Cherry Darling firing a gun with the leg?

Comment: Very carefully.

Comment: You're looking for plausible mechanical realism in that movie?  Really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently by magic or telepathic command.

At several points the gun clearly fires without her hands being anywhere near the trigger mechanism. (Unfortunately, the actual picture of the shot blast is mid-frame and so very blurry) but the gun clearly fires **by itself**

[image]

You can watch the whole thing here.

By the end the has been upgraded from a modified M4 Carbine with a M203 grenade launcher attachment to a **minigun**!

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks terrible. I hope it's on Netflix!

Answer (score 2):

The gun fires by electrical impulse.  Much in the same way as "bionic" arms and legs are still usable by amputees, down to very touch-sensitive fingers, Cherry need only send an electrical impulse to her leg via her brain in order to fire the weapon.  Think of it as, how does your big toe move?  You send a signal to that muscle via your brain, and the toe moves.  In Cherry's case, she sends a signal to move her toe, and the gun fires.  You don't need to physically touch the trigger any more than an amputee needs to physically touch their bionic fingers to make them move.

And **no**, this is not explained in the movie.  But it's a logical conclusion.

Comment: It's not much of a logical conclusion, though. The logical conclusion is that she had a *friggin' gun for a leg* in a grindhouse movie from Robert Rodriguez.

Answer (score 0):

Artificial limbs connect a nerve to activate the cluster of motors. When a nerve impulse is sent the sensor picks up the motor neuron signal and sends it to the motor to move. The gun may have an electric trigger.